# jQuery collapse function in expandable (accordion) list not working when anchor tags are used

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery (scripts.js) to implement an accordion list.  The content of the list is generated from the following php code:

```
$resultf = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM groups WHERE name LIKE 'f%' ORDER BY name");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultf))
  {
  printf("<li><a href='http://www.domain.com/list/viewgroup.php?id=%s'>%s<br></a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                            Info line 1<br>
            Info line 2<br>
                    </li>
               </ul>
          </li>", $row['id'], $row['name']);  }
```

The first tier of the list is intended to contain hyperlinks (sidenote: I know that the jQuery script turns off the hyperlinks but I've found a way to fix that).  Nevertheless, the anchor tags used to create the hyperlinks in the first tier seem to interfere with the collapse function.  More specifically, the collapse function will hide all lines (including the first tier hyperlinks) rather than just the two lines containing "Info line 1" and "Info line 2".

While troubleshooting this, I deleted the anchor tags from the printf line and everything works fine, except for the fact that the links are not clickable hyperlinks.

Can someone explain to me why the anchor tags cause such a problem and possibly provide a solution?  Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You are missing quotes around the link url. Is this intentional?

Comment: No, sorry.  I will add those back.  I took them out when I deleted the anchor tags while I was troubleshooting.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why someone might have voted down my question?  If my question is inappropriate for some reason, I would benefit from knowing why.  Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jpinksta/R7zaT/ Here is a jsfiddle I created which demonstrates the issue.  I was not able to upload the + and - graphics before the Tier 1 list but you can still expand or collapse individually by clicking directly to the left of those lines.  You'll see that when "collapse all" function is clicked, the Tier 1 which is a hyperlink vanishes while the other Tier 1 which is regular text remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with someone who provided a solution.  One possible fix is changing:

$('.collapsed').children('').show('medium');
to 
$('.collapsed').children('ul').show('medium');

and

$('.collapsed').children('').hide('medium'); 
to 
$('.collapsed').children('ul').hide('medium');

Thanks to haxbth for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle to show this working  - http://jsfiddle.net/R7zaT/3/

You were adding the collapsed class to the `<li>` which should be on the `<ul>` below to keep the text in place.

I changed the following:

```
.addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').children('ul').hide();
```

to

```
.children().addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').children('ul').hide();
```

This added the class to the child of the `<li>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.  I experimented with the fiddle you created and the collapse all function works great.  However, the list loads expanded and I was having trouble with the expand feature (both individually and expand all) after the items had been collapsed.  The trouble wasn't consistent.  Sometimes those features would work but sometimes they wouldn't.  I'm also not sure why my fiddle works fine if I just delete the anchor tags in the line with the href.  I think the anchor tags throw off the javascript, but I don't know exactly how or how to fix it.  Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for the page to start with all collapsed then? Is the hyperlink tier supposed to expand or just link to somewhere without expanding?

Comment: I have updated the fiddle link in the answer. The button functionality code you had was applying to the children too which needed taking out. The last part will depend on how you intend the hyperlink to work.

Comment: I'm looking for the list to start collapsed.  Each of the "Tier 1" labeled lines then expand with two lines beneath each.  I would normally have a "+" image in front of the Tier 1 lines but I didn't know how to upload the image in the fiddle.  That image changes to a "-" when the item has been expanded.  The hyperlink is an actual link when clicked on, but the + and - in front of it allow the list to expand and collapse.  In my fiddle if you delete the anchor tags, it works perfectly (but I lose the hyperlink functionality).  I think the anchor tags and collapse all script are at odds.

Comment: On the updated fiddle, the expand all works great after collapse all is used.  However, if I collapse one or both individually, the expand all doesn't seem to work.  I really appreciate your effort to help me out.  You script suggestions are helping me to think and learn about it.  I really think the problem lies in the anchor tags, but if I knew for sure I wouldn't have to ask for help.  It is appreciated.